# Strongswan to WatchGuard connected but no traffic

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, routing, strongswan

[image]

I'm connecting to a client's Watchguard VPN with StrongSwan on my AWS hosted Ubuntu 22 machine. I have a connection established but there is zero traffic flowing. I can't ping the destination and the folks on the other end can't reach my machine.

On my tester windows machine it connects and allows me to ping the 172.30.101.11 w/o any issues as Watchguard includes connection profile/script for ios,android and windows but nothing for Linux :/

**aws inbound ports**

Enabled 4500 and 500 UDP inbound + ESP(50) all ports.

**ipsec.conf**

```
conn PHS-IKEv2-VPN
     left=172.31.89.153
     leftid=USERNAME
     leftauth=eap-mschapv2
     type=tunnel
     ike=aes256-sha256-modp2048
     esp=aes256-sha256-modp2048
     right=8.50.50.3
     rightid=%any
     auto=start
     rightsubnet=172.30.101.11/32
     rightauth=pubkey
     modeconfig=pull *also tired push here. no difference
     leftsourceip=%config
```

I'm not real keen on custom routing so I went to my windows machine and mirrored the routes to the best of my ability

**Confirmed ip forwarding was enabled at the ubuntu system level**

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Table 220 routes. **the first one was created by strongswan** the rest were the ones I mirrored from the windows machine but I get the same result with and without the additional routes.

```
172.30.101.11 via 172.31.80.1 dev ens5 proto static src 10.184.123.129     
8.50.50.3 via 172.31.80.1 dev ens5 src 172.31.89.153
10.0.0.0/8 dev ens5 scope link src 10.184.123.129
10.184.123.129 dev ens5 scope link src 10.184.123.129
10.255.255.255 dev ens5 scope link src 10.184.123.129
255.255.255.255 dev ens5 scope link src 10.184.123.129
```

**Other routes (system/aws generated routes)**

```
sudo ip route show table main
```

default via 172.31.80.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp metric 100
default via 172.31.80.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp src 172.31.89.153 metric 100
169.254.0.0/16 dev ens5 scope link metric 1000
172.31.0.2 via 172.31.80.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp src 172.31.89.153 metric 100
172.31.80.0/20 dev ens5 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.89.153 metric 100
172.31.80.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp scope link src 172.31.89.153 metric 100

**ipsec Statusall:**

```
Listening IP addresses:
  172.31.89.153
Connections:
IKEv2-VPN:  172.31.89.153...8.50.50.3  IKEv1/2
IKEv2-VPN:   local:  [USERNAME] uses EAP_MSCHAPV2 authentication
IKEv2-VPN:   remote: uses public key authentication
IKEv2-VPN:   child:  dynamic === 172.30.101.11/32 TUNNEL
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
IKEv2-VPN[1]: ESTABLISHED 17 minutes ago, 172.31.89.153[USERNAME]...8.50.50.3[O=WatchGuard, OU=Fireware, CN=ike2muvpn Server]
IKEv2-VPN[1]: IKEv2 SPIs: a8540d486c9c39c0_i* 16392ad532fb0bcc_r, EAP reauthentication in 2 hours
IKEv2-VPN[1]: IKE proposal: AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/MODP_2048
IKEv2-VPN{1}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 1, ESP in UDP SPIs: c26bfd03_i 8e77f201_o
IKEv2-VPN{1}:  AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128, 0 bytes_i, 0 bytes_o, rekeying in 29 minutes
IKEv2-VPN{1}:   10.184.123.129/32 === 172.30.101.11/32
```

**Logs**

```
Sep 11 04:54:55 14[IKE] IKE_SA PHS-IKEv2-VPN[1] established between 172.31.89.153[GH_Remote]...8.53.54.171[O=WatchGuard, OU=Fireware, CN=ike2muvpn Server]
Sep 11 04:54:55 14[IKE] scheduling reauthentication in 10190s
Sep 11 04:54:55 14[IKE] maximum IKE_SA lifetime 10730s
Sep 11 04:54:55 14[IKE] installing DNS server 54.174.40.213 to /etc/resolv.conf
Sep 11 04:54:55 14[IKE] installing DNS server 52.3.100.184 to /etc/resolv.conf
Sep 11 04:54:55 14[CFG] handling INTERNAL_IP4_SUBNET attribute failed
Sep 11 04:54:55 14[IKE] installing new virtual IP 10.184.123.129
Sep 11 04:54:55 14[CFG] selected proposal: ESP:AES_CBC_256/HMAC_SHA2_256_128/NO_EXT_SEQ
Sep 11 04:54:55 14[IKE] CHILD_SA PHS-IKEv2-VPN{1} established with SPIs c7ee10bb_i cecb1240_o and TS 10.184.123.129/32 === 172.30.101.11/32
Sep 11 04:54:55 14[IKE] peer supports MOBIKE
Sep 11 04:56:56 06[IKE] sending keep alive to 8.53.54.171[4500]
Sep 11 04:58:56 10[IKE] sending keep alive to 8.53.54.171[4500]
```

**Ping from 10.x interface:(same response with a normal ping)**

```
ping -I 10.184.123.129 172.30.101.11
PING 172.30.101.11 (172.30.101.11) from 10.184.123.129 : 56(84) bytes of data
```

**Corresponding TCP Dump**

```
sudo tcpdump -v  -i ens5 dst 172.30.101.11
tcpdump: listening on ens5, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
11:01:23.464363 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 49668, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
ip-172-31-89-153 > 172.30.101.11: ICMP echo request, id 132, seq 1, length 64
```

Comment: Do you receive the ESP-in-UDP (or even just ESP) packets on your `ens5` interface when you're being pinged? Does your host send ESP-in-UDP packets when it tries to ping the other host?

Comment: @u1686_grawity I will need to get with the network engineer on the other end to get an answer on that. He is slightly elusive but I will update as soon as I can get that info.

Comment: You can run Wireshark or tcpdump on your side and get the answer at least to the 2nd part (by watching Wireshark while trying to ping the other end). Packet capture does get slightly weird when IPsec is involved, but in this case I *think* it should show the encrypted packets.

Comment: (As a side note, at some point it might be worth trying to set up strongSwan to use an "xfrmi" interface – so that it would work in the more familiar "virtual interface" mode rather than the IPsec "magic transform" mode – to make the routing setup more familiar. Though this also might need migrating from the obsolete ipsec.conf to swanctl...)

Comment: this is all I see when I do `sudo tcpdump -i ens5 dst 172.30.101.11`: `05:28:06.253724 IP ip-172-31-89-153 > 172.30.101.11: ICMP echo request, id 113, seq 10, length 64` over and over while I ping

Comment: It seems to be ignoring the `src` hint in the route that strongSwan has set up. Do you have anything in `ip -4 rule` that would cause it to ignore table 220? Does `ping -I 10.184.123.129 172.30.101.11` work any better?

Comment: same behavior when I ping from 10.x. and the ip -4 command appears to have a reference to 220.

Comment: Check that Ubuntu level system IP forwarding is enabled in conjunction with the "forwarding=1 in the strongswan.conf" as you mention but see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/311053/how-to-make-ip-forwarding-permanent. Also, you might check the AWS side NAT configuration if that's applicable in your case for NAT'ing. Also as previously mentioned, ensure UDP traffic is allowed through your FW rules if applicable.

Comment: thanks @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle I updated my question to show that the ip forwarding was enabled at the ubuntu system level not in the strongswan.conf.  Not exactly sure what to look for in the NAT config on the AWS side but I will do some research on the topic.